# Eigenvectors of $a_{ij} = \frac{x_i}{x_i-x_j}$, $i \neq j$ otherwise $a_{ii} = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{x_i}{x_i-x_j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a pairwise distinct vector of reals $[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ and for any such vector, we create a matrix $A_n$ such that

$$a_{ij} = \frac{x_i}{x_i-x_j}$$ where $i \neq j$ and $$a_{ii} = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{x_i}{x_i-x_j} $$

What can be said about the set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of any $A_n$?

So far I have been only able to deduce that the eigenvalues of $A_n$ will be $[n-1,n-2,...,0]$ but I am having a difficult time understanding the pattern of the left eigenvectors. How can I find and prove a concrete formula for the eigenvectors of any matrix $A_n$ created from the vector $[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$?

Addendum: The eigenvalues and associated left eigenvectors for $A_4$ are shown below. [image]

The pattern I have been able to deduce is that for $A_n$, we have the eigenvalues $\{0,...,n-1\}$ and associated with each eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have the following way to construct a basis of the eigenvector

1. For a given $e_k$ we take $\{x_1,...x_n\}\setminus {x_k}$ and we take all the subsets of size $(n-1)-\lambda$.
2. $e_k$ is then the sum of the product of these subsets

for example above, for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$, we take all $(4-1)-2 = 1$-sized subsets from $\{x_1,...x_n\}\setminus {x_k}$ and sum them up, which works out.

But why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I am reverse engineering this:

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients  of degree $<n$.
For $f\in V$ put $A(f) = X\frac{df}{dX}$. Then $A:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear map.
Its eigenvectors are the monomials of degree $0,1,\ldots, n-1$ with
eigenvalues $0,1,\ldots, n-1$.

With respect to a suitable basis $e_k$ the map $A$ is multiplication by
the matrix $(a_{ij})$ of this exercise.  Indeed, let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be distinct real numbers
and let $f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^n(X-x_i)$.
Now put $e_k=f(X)/(X-x_k)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Apologies for the very late reply, I'm not sure I follow your answer, although it seems correct. I have added an example of 4 eigenvectors I found using computational methods for $A_4$, how do these match your scheme?

Comment: The coordinates of your eigenvectors are the coefficients of my polynomials $e_k$. Up to an irrelevant  sign.   For instance, when $n=4$, we have $e_1=(X-x_2)(X-x_3)(X-x_4)= X^3-(x_2+x_3+x_4)X^2+(x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)X-x_2x_3x_4$. There are similar expressions for $e_2$, $e_3$ and $e_4$.  The vector of $X^3$-coefficients of  $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ and $e_4$ is $[1,1,1,1]$. It is your eigenvector with eigenvalue $3$.  The vector of $X^2$-coefficients is
$[x_2+x_3+x_4,x_1+x_3+x_4,x_1+x_2+x_4,x_1+x_2+x_3]$. It is your eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$, etc.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for your answer. I have given you the green tick but could you please expand on why $A(f) = X\frac{df}{dX}$ is the multiplication by the matrix $A$?

Comment: Both the map  $f\mapsto X\frac{df}{dX}$ and multiplication by your matrix $a_{ij}$ are linear maps with eigenvalues $0,1,\ldots,n-1$. Therefore they are the same up to a change of basis